# What does --file command does in package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "build:icons": "rollup ./generated_js/index.js --file ./dist/icons.js --format es --name \"svgs\""
  },
```

What does `--file` does?

In `index.js`, I have this:

[image: Index.js]

In `./dist/icons.js`, I have this:

[image: icons.js]

I want to know what does `--file` do exactly, and why is the `export {..}` statement included in `icons.js` file, and how to remove it from there.

Comment: Read manual: https://rollupjs.org/command-line-interface/#command-line-flags

Comment: As @Justinas points out, `--file` in this case is just an argument passed to a script defined in the `package.json` file. This particular script can probably be run with `npm run build:icons`, but what the actual script does is unrelated to the syntax of the `package.json` itself.

Comment: @Boaz `is just an argument passed to a script` - this doesn't really tell me anything. What does `--file` do exactly? Why is the `export {..}` statement included in the output file? How is this output file created, and how is it determine what is inside? Please be more specific.

Comment: @ILoveCoffee The question is not about `package.json`. The question is about the rollup CLI that Justinas linked to above. Look into that first. If you have another question, open it separately with the relevant details.

Comment: I have looked into it! There is nothing in that documentation that answers my question, that's why I am asking here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally scripts:build will create a build file ,  --file with output file name ( which you havent mentioned , if you mention any file name the output of build file will be stored in that file which you have mentioned.)

useful source of info can be found here :

https://rollupjs.org/command-line-interface/#command-line-flags

Comment: Isn't this the output file: `./dist/icons.js`?

Comment: So is `icons.js` the `build file`? Why is the `export {..}` statement include in it, and how do I remove it?